# (Self-Signed) Certificate revoked in IE mode, but not in Edge mode

Tags: windows, certificate, internet-explorer, chrome

I am using a self-signed certificate which is working fine when using Chrome or Edge. Both browsers show that the connection is secure and that the certificate is valid.

An application using the WinInet-API to access the same website, however, fails with ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_REVOKED (12170) and the error message:

> The security certificate for this site has been revoked. This site should not be trusted.

When checking the certificate using certutil (as shown here:
[How do I check if my SSL certificates have been revoked](https://serverfault.com/questions/590504/how-do-i-check-if-my-ssl-certificates-have-been-revoked) ), the certificate is being shown as revoked:

[image]

[image]

Also, when using the IE-mode of Edge, a certificate error is shown:

[image]

Translation:

[image]

What could be the reason that the certificate is only revoked when using the IE mode, but neither Chrome nor Edge show it as revoked?

I have seen a similar issue being discussed here ( [FireFox detects Revoked Certificate, IE does not](https://serverfault.com/questions/53984/firefox-detects-revoked-certificate-ie-does-not) ), but in my case, it's basically the opposite with only IE showing the certificate as being revoked.

Comment: I've found a thread discussing possible cases why a certificate might incorrectly being shown as revoked: https://serverfault.com/questions/338527/why-might-windows-falsely-claim-a-self-signed-root-ca-certificate-is-revoked?rq=1